# Two similar rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

There are two similar rebus puzzles below. Each of them hides a word.

Puzzle 1:

[image: Rebus1]

Puzzle 2:

[image: Rebus2]

Your task is to find out the hidden word in both of these puzzles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puzzle 1:

> Eye + L& = Island

Puzzle 2:

> Eyes + L& = Iceland

Comment: I though I was looking at capital i's, not lowercase l's.

Comment: same here.  tricky.